# What's the meaning of doing an && operation on two different operands one pointer to node and other an int type?

Tags: c, data-structures, tree, binary-search-tree

I was going through a ques in which two nodes of a BST are swapped.We need to find that two nodes and swap it again to gain the original BST(http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/fix-two-swapped-nodes-of-bst/)
    While going through the code,in function correctBSTUtil()

```
if (*prev && root->data < (*prev)->data)
```

I can't figure out what's the meaning of doing an && operation on two different operands one pointer to node and other an int type
and when this condition will become true or false(an example will be helpful).
I tried to search but couldn't find much more about this.
Thanks for your suggestions!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<` operator takes precedence over `&&` operator. ([c language operator precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence))

```
if (*prev && root->data < (*prev)->data)
```

means

```
if (*prev && (root->data < (*prev)->data))
```

not

```
if ((*prev && root->data) < (*prev)->data)
```

So the code is doing logical and operation between `*prev` and `root->data < (*prev)->data`.

Also, `0` or `NULL` is considered as `false` in c language.

Since the code applies `->` operator on `*prev`, `prev` seems to be a pointer to pointer, resulting in `*prev` being a pointer. It may be `NULL`, in which case it will be evaluated as `false` in conditional expression.

Note also that `*prev` must be the left side of `&&` in this case so that if `*prev` is `NULL` the `if` condition is `false` already and the program won't evaluate `root->data < (*prev)->data` at all, preventing segmentation fault of trying to dereference a `NULL` pointer.

Answer (score 1):

It's a shorthand for

```
if (*prev != nullptr && root->data < (*prev)->data)
```

Note that prev seems to be a pointer to a pointer.

Comment: `nullptr` is pure C++ and is not a part of C at all.

Comment: Thanks :) @Stefan Haustein